# Spring Security - Principal from Authorization Server is different from Resource Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I created `userinfo` endpoint in my authorization server.

```
@GetMapping("/userinfo")
public Principal me(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

It returns this JSON:

```
{
    ...
    "userAuthentication": {
        ...
        "principal": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "xyz",
            "password": "......",
            "accountNonExpired": true,
            "accountNonLocked": true,
            "credentialsNonExpired": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "authorities": [
                {
                "authority": "ROLE_DONOR"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2019-11-08T20:50:46"
        },
        ...
        "name": "xyz"
    },
    ...
    "principal": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "xyz",
        "password": "......",
        "accountNonExpired": true,
        "accountNonLocked": true,
        "credentialsNonExpired": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "authorities": [
        {
            "authority": "ROLE_DONOR"
        }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2019-11-08T20:50:46"
    },
    ...
    "name": "xyz"
}
```

In one of my Resource Servers, User Service API, I tried to `sysout` the value of `Principal` just to see its value:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResourceResponseDto findById(@PathVariable("id") long id, Principal principal) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String x = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(principal);
    System.out.println(x);
    return ...;
}
```

The value of `principal` is different. Its value is equivalent to above `principal.username`, leaving out other fields:

```
{
    "userAuthentication": {
        ...
        "principal": "xyz",
        ...
        "name": "xyz"
    },
    ...
    "principal": "xyz",
    ...
    "name": "xyz"
}
```

How does that happen?

I need to get the value of `id` but it's gone. The fields of `principal`object are gone. That causes I think error for my other method:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or #id == principal.id")
public ResourceResponseDto findById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    //
}
```

I'm getting this error;

```
Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRole('ADMIN') or #id == principal.id'
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Start by examining _what class_ the `Principal` is in each of these cases.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you are implementing OAuth2 Spring Authentication Server.
`Principle` is just an interface that declares the method `getName()`. For authentication and resource servers `principle` is implemented by the class `OAuth2Authentication`. method `getPrinciple()`:

```
public Object getPrincipal() {
    return this.userAuthentication == null ? this.storedRequest.getClientId() : this.userAuthentication.getPrincipal();
}
```

If OAuth2 client is being authenticated, it does not have an `userAuthentication`, just `clientId`. If user is being authenticated, you see full `userAuthentication` object.

Answer (score 1):

from the `Authentication.getPrincipal()` documentation:

> The identity of the principal being authenticated. In the case of an authentication request with username and password, this would be the username. Callers are expected to populate the principal for an authentication request.
>   The AuthenticationManager implementation will often return an
>   Authentication containing richer information as the principal for use by
>   the application. Many of the authentication providers will create a
>   UserDetails object as the principal.

So, you are in charge of populating the `Principal` on the authentication process.

One of the way to pass additional info to the `Principal`, is by extending the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and overriding the 'attemptAuthentication()' method:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, 
                 HttpServletResponse response) {
    String username = obtainUsername(request);
    String password = obtainPassword(request);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    setDetails(request, authRequest);

    Authentication authenticated = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            new YourObjectForPrincipal(...),
            authenticated.getCredentials(), authenticated.getAuthorities());
}
```

Note passing the `YourObjectForPrincipal` object, that could contain any data you want, as the first parameter to the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.
To get your extended user, just cast to the desired object:

```
(YourObjectForPrincipal)authentication.getPrincipal();
```

It's might be not the best solution, but it worked for me.
I hope it will help.

Comment: Will I implement this in Authorization Server? And the `YourObjectForPrincipal` refers to my object that contains`id`, `username`, etc., correct?

Comment: @Julez you can add it on either side. For the Resource server, you can add it via AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter()

Comment: I created a class that extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` with a constructor that accepts `AuthenticationManager` instance. I replaced `this.getAuthenticationManager()` with `this.authenticationManager.`. In my auth server config, I had this: `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(this.authenticationManager))`. But it's still the same.

Comment: I can't do that in Resource Server (API) as `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` does not have `@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oAuthServer) throws Exception {...}`.

Comment: You are right. I specified proposal for Auth Server. The `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` has `configure(HttpSecurity http)`. You could use `http.addFilterBefore(yourFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` to add your filter.

Comment: Which means I will need `YourObjectForPrincipal` class in my Resource Server, right?

Comment: Correct. You just get the `Principal` from the Auth Server and extend it with your data by passing extended object instead of the former `Principal`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late but here is my solution.
Since I used **UserInfoTokenServices** in my resource server, I found it uses **FixedPrincipalExtractor**, in this class I see this:

```
private static final String[] PRINCIPAL_KEYS = new String[] { "user", "username",
            "userid", "user_id", "login", "id", "name" };

    @Override
    public Object extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {
        for (String key : PRINCIPAL_KEYS) {
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                return map.get(key);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So it directly returned the 'user' value which in your app is 'xyz'.
So I created a class to implement **PrincipalExtractor** and override the **extractPrincipal** method:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.PrincipalExtractor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.project.LoginUser;

@Component
public class CustomPrincipalExtractor implements PrincipalExtractor {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Map<String, Object> principal = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("principal");
        return JSON.parseObject(JSON.toJSONString(principal), LoginUser.class);
    }

}
```

Here the param map is similar to **Principal** in authorization server so I get my LoginUser class with the 'principal' key which implemented UserDetails and added some additional info like id, email...  just like your principal. Here I used fastjson to parse it, you can also use ObjectMapper.
Then defined the UserInfoTokenServices bean in your resource server. Here is my code:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final ResourceServerProperties sso;
    private final CustomPrincipalExtractor customPrincipalExtractor;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public UserInfoTokenServices tokenService() {
        UserInfoTokenServices userInfoTokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(sso.getUserInfoUri(), sso.getClientId());
        userInfoTokenServices.setPrincipalExtractor(customPrincipalExtractor);
        return userInfoTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here I created a **UserInfoTokenServices** and set my custom **PrincipalExtractor**. Don't forget to add these properties:

```
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri = http://domain:port/your/user-info-url
security.oauth2.resource.prefer-token-info = false
```

Now you can get your own principal object in your resource server.